# Package.json has a version of a Package that doesn't actually exist. what happens?

Tags: node.js, npm, version

I'm supporting a project that has a version of the following package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-typeahead-bootstrap

the version in the package.json says we imported version 2.6.0 however the lastest version currently is 2.5.3 beta. I would have to assume someone manually changed this. So if the version specified is beyond the version that currently exists, is it smart enough to just take the latest version. and will it automatically update the the newest version until it hits 2.6.0?

I'm gonna just change it match the current version anyway, but I was curious if anyone knew the functionality of this.

Comment: I know you solved this a different way, but I'm curious if you found out if it will automatically update to the newest version before 2.6.0?

Answer (score 1):

Please look at versions of this package
[image: Version history]
The version 2.6.0 goes prior 2.5.x versions